# Solution of transcendental equation in with Matlab

Tags: matlab, equation

I have an equation which goes like this:
[image]

Here, I_L(lambdap) is the modified bessel function. This and product with exponential function can be written in matlab as besseli(L,lambdap,1). "i" stands for square root of -1. I want to solve:

> 1+pt+it=0

where I have to vary 'k' and find values of 'w'. I had posted *similar* problem at [mathematica stack exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162643/solution-of-transcendental-equation), but I couldn't solve the problem fully, though i have got a [clue](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2181-numerical-methods-using-matlab--2e?focused=5042433&tab=function)  (please go through the comments at [mathematica stack exchange site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162643/solution-of-transcendental-equation)). I could not convert my equation to the code that has been posted in [clue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162643/solution-of-transcendental-equation). Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I never attempted this before, but... is this returning a suitable result?

```
syms w k;
fun = 1 + pt(w,k) + it(w,k);
sol = vpasolve(fun == 0,w,k);

disp(sol.w);
disp(sol.k);

function res = pt(w,k)
    eps_l0 = w / (1.22 * k);
    lam_k = 0.25 * k^2;

    res = sym('res',[5 1]);
    res_off = 1;

    for L = -2:2
        gam = besseli(L,lam_k) * exp(-lam_k);
        eps_z = (w - L) / (1.22 * k);
        zeta = 1i * sqrt(pi()) * exp(-eps_z^2) * (1 + erfc(1i * eps_z));

        res(res_off,:) = ((25000 * gam) / k^2) * (1 + (eps_l0 * zeta));
        res_off = res_off + 1;
    end

    res = sum(res);
end

function res = it(w,k)
    eps_l0 = (w - (0.86 * k)) / (3.46 * k);
    lam_k = 0.03 * k^2;

    res = sym('res',[5 1]);
    res_off = 1;

    for L = -2:2
        gam = besseli(L,lam_k) * exp(-lam_k);
        eps_z = (w - (8 * L) - (0.86 * k)) / (3.46 * k);
        zeta = 1i * sqrt(pi()) * exp(-eps_z^2) * (1 + erfc(1i * eps_z));

        res(res_off,:) = ((2000000 * gam) / k^2) * (1 + (eps_l0 * zeta));
        res_off = res_off + 1;
    end

    res = sum(res);
end
```

**EDIT**

For numeric k and symbolic w:

```
syms w;

for k = -3:3
    fun = 1 + pt(w,k) + it(w,k);
    sol = vpasolve(fun == 0,w);
    disp(sol.w);
end
```

Comment: I have made a small correction in the question. I want to vary k and then find w (i have edited the question). How this can be incorporated?

Comment: It's almost the same logic. You create w as symbolic and use k as numeric.

Comment: thanks for looking into my problem. When i ran the file I am getting an error: `Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.

Error in sym/subsref (line 776)
            R_tilde = builtin('subsref',L_tilde,Idx);

Error in Untitled (line 5)
    disp(sol.w);`
The way that i did was to separately create function 'pt' and 'it' and then run the program. Any thoughts?